# How Can I use Mkdocs on local computer without server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mkdocs

I installed Mkdocs (Python 3.6.5) and edited and built Markdown files.

I tried to open the main index.html file with a browser, but I cannot directly open HTML pages linked to other HTML files.

Using Command Prompt and typing "mkdocs serve", I can open linked pages. I know this is a normal function of Mkdocs without server.

Can I use Mkdocs just on my local computer?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [doc](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#use_directory_urls), you can add `use_directory_urls: false` in `mkdocs.yml` and rebuild it.

> The default style of `use_directory_urls: true` creates more user friendly URLs, and is usually what you'll want to use. The alternate style (edit: `use_directory_urls: false`) can occasionally be useful if you want your documentation to remain properly linked when opening pages directly from the file system, because it creates links that point directly to the target file rather than the target directory.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to accept the answer to help others with similar problem

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation you can generate html files with `mkdocs build`. They will be stored in folder called `site`. You can open built files without having to run `mkdocs serve`.